CallbackRouteError when trying to sign in with Azure AD provider, but always works at the second attempt
I want to clarify that I'm new to web development, especially in Sveltekit, so I apologize in advance if I've forgotten to mention any essential points for debugging.
I've added a new Azure AD identity provider to my Cognito client, so now i can sign in either by using a Cognito user or by using my Azure AD account, the issue that i'm facing is that when i try to sign in using the Azure AD identity provider i get this error in the logs
2024-05-06T09:57:56.900+02:00   [31m[auth][error][0m CallbackRouteError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror
2024-05-06T09:57:56.900+02:00   at Module.callback (file:///node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/index.js:248:23)
2024-05-06T09:57:56.900+02:00   at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
2024-05-06T09:57:56.900+02:00   at async AuthInternal (file:///node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:27:24)
2024-05-06T09:57:56.900+02:00   at async Auth (file:///node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:104:29)
2024-05-06T09:57:56.900+02:00   at async respond (file:///server/chunks/index-f482eaae.js:3574:22)
2024-05-06T09:57:56.900+02:00   at async Array.ssr (file:///handler.js:1221:3)

But then when i try to sign in again right after this first attempt, it magically works, but i noticed that it's not the same token that is used, so i don't understand what i'm doing wrong or not
I tried changes in the attributes mapping thinking it could be an issue from this side, but seems like it isn't.
